# Template option not coming for a new user even access to user for template is provided

Tags: sitecore-client

Template option is not coming for a new user even access to user for template is provided. I have created a new user and provide `sitecore/developer` role to it and in `security editor` manually provide all the access for template but still no template options is coming when i am logging in as new user.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are the options for other users? Are they configured on Standard Values?

Comment: With on Sitecore/Developer role, you can get access to the template via desktop. So, instead of clicking on content editor from launchpad, click on the Desktop icon. Now, from desktop, click on Sitecore menu (red button at the left bottom). You'll see the template manager from the menu.

Comment: Is there any role through which i can directly give access of templates to user from content editor

Answer (score 2):

If you have added proper role to the user or provided access directly to the user and still the templates not coming in the content editor then check the View option in the menu, You suppose to select both "Hidden Items" and "Entire Tree".

Mostly these will be unchecked for the newly created users.

[image]